# Is SQL Server Thread Safe?

Tags: sql-server, concurrency, sql-server-2012

If I need to update same row with two concurrent thread then is it possible in SQL Server?

Suppose I have one table that contains `Id` and `Name` columns and now I want to update the third number Id with Name 'xyz' using one thread. Using the other thread, I want to update the same name which I am updating using the first thread, but it gives error like your connection is in connecting state. I can't update the data.

Does anyone know how to solve it? Do I need to assign a lock?

Comment: are you reusing connection objects?

Comment: Are you working with ADO.NET?

Comment: Yes.I am working with ADO.Net in wpf application. When i update data in first thread : i open the connection and after ExecuteQuery() i close it and in second thread i did the same

Answer (score 3):

> Is Sql server thread-safe?

This issue is not with that SQL Server being thread safe or not.The issue is there with [SQL Server Connection Pooling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca.aspx)

**In Short:**- Whenever a user calls Open on a connection, the pooler looks for an available connection in the pool. If a pooled connection is available, it returns it to the caller instead of opening a new connection. More reading from the link above.

Things to try with Connection object to fix this

- Don't reuse connections or any ADO.NET objects at all and don't make them static.
- Always create, open(in case of Connections), use, close and dispose them where you need them
- Use the [using-statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose and close(Connections) implicitely

Now update on same row:
If the update statement are to acquire a row/table lock, for instance, any other update process to the same row/table at the same time would be blocked.

Further Reading:

[Locking and Row Versioning](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187101(v=sql.105).aspx)
and [Table Hints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms187373.aspx)

Comment: Connection pooling solved the problem but now the execution of two threads are to be done randomly. sometimes the First thread update executes and sometimes second thread gets update.  So what can i Say SQL Server is not thread safe thats why this happens??

Comment: If the update statement are to acquire a row/table lock, for instance, any other update process to the same row/table at the same time would be blocked.I have added these in post

Comment: yes but i am asking that what does it mean? does it mean that SQl Server meant to be thread-safe as it handles blocking stuff itself?? i am a beginner so don't know detail stuff about this..

Comment: To answer you question in simple word, yes it is. there is lot more on it like deadlock.

Answer (score 1):

From the database perspective, this can be configured with isolation levels. Be aware that every isolation has some scenarios which can be solved but also with a certain impact. I think the wikipedia article is very clear for a first step. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_(database_systems)

If you do not want/can't solve it with your database, you have to look what your application server stack offers you for thread synchronizations.