# How many operations SQL Server support per connection

Tags: sql-server-2012, connection-pooling, multi-thread

I am making a multi threaded application in which I will use a single SQL Server connection and perform select, insert, update and delete.

So once my application starts, it will open connection with SQL Server and then multiple threads will run each doing select, insert, update and delete (in no particular order) on multiple tables using the same connection.

I want to ask how many operations can SQL Server handle for a single connection?

Comment: What is the CPU, Memory and disk performance for this server?  What are the *actual* queries being run?  What is the exact schema (including indexes, triggers, etc.) for the database?  Is your database supporting only transactional workloads or must it also support analytical/reporting?  .... There are a LOT of variables.  But I would guess at easily hundreds.

Comment: Why are you limiting yourself to a single connection? A connection pool would be safer and probably require less effort on your part (as there are libraries, etc. that have already implemented them).

Comment: You may be right. I think using a `using` block would be much better than using a single connection.

Comment: The common using/open/execute pattern handles multiple threads well and leverages connection pooling too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> a multi threaded application in which I will use a single SQL Server connection

Bad idea. A database connection usually is not thread-safe, and as you suspect, at any one time one connection can only execute one statement. You should open a separate connection for each application thread instead, or at least use a connection pool shared between the threads.

Comment: You may be right. I think using a `using` block would be much better than using a single connection. And connection pooling is automatically handled by SQL Server as per following links so I don't need to worry about it (at least if threads are reasonable for e.g. running 20 threads simultaneously and not 200000)  

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/77060/is-sql-server-thread-safe  

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21731641/sqlconnection-thread-safe  


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7316304/is-sqlconnection-sqlcommand-thread-safe

Comment: I'm not arguing with you, just pointing out a limitation. Also, the OP says "will run each doing select, insert, update and delete", so interleaved selects won't really cut it, I don't think.

Comment: Oh, sure thing.  I definitely don't think MARS is the answer here.  In retrospect, I was just being pedantic.